# What can be done to fix the following error when we run any rails command: " `require_relative': cannot load such file "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Any rails command doesn't work for me. I have several versions of ruby installed through rvm. I tried installing rails with all the versions, they do install successfully but with all of them I face the following error whenever I run **any** rails command in my project directory:

```
~ rails new blog
Traceback (most recent call last): 
1: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/Am33d/Documents/config/boot (LoadError)
```

I tried looking up for the error but didn't find any solutions.

What can be done to fix this? I am using macOS Mojave (10.14.6)

Answer (score 6):

This error would indicate that you do not have a `boot.rb` file in your config directory for some reason. When running rails commands -- regardless of if you run them as `bin/rails [command]` or `bundle exec rails [command]`, runs the `bin/rails` file. This file typically has a line `require_relative '../config/boot`. The boilerplate `bin/rails` file in a new Rails 6 app is:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

To simply fix this you can create a blank file by running `touch config/boot.rb` from the root directory of your application and that would itself suppress the error. Having said that, you'd be better off creating a `config/boot.rb` file that contains useful information. The boilerplate `config/boot.rb` file is this

```rb
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

Without this file you are not necessarily appropriately loading the gems from your gemfile or caching operations with bootsnap.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem, I also received the same error when trying to use rails -s.

If the same is happening for you, its because your version of ruby isn't compatible with your rails version.

After upgrading to the latest rails version the error stopped and everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit weird.

**rails new blog** should not need to find boot file, neither need bundler. Actually, you are trying to create a new project, so it is expected there is not Gemfile, boot, or bundler created for your project.

So I would advise you to find what rails command is being executed. Sometimes one rails executable created by bundler is taking precedence in the $PATH environment variable.

Ex: some incorrect bin/rails executable is on your $HOME directory.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to build an app using 'rails server' and this error was showing. You have to make sure that the rails version matches the ruby version and even if you do what an answer above said (create the config/boot.rb paste) doesnt work, than you have to change the version of rails to the stable. I'll let the link of this problem here, there's an issue closed in github for this problem https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43951

to solve the problem you have to replace the gem rails line on the gemfile to this:

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "7-0-stable"
```

Sorry about my english.